# How do I change the default number of parameters SDI 12?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sensors

I am a nooby so this might be an obvious answer kind of a question, but how do I change how many parameters arduino-uno reads from a sensor using SDI communication? My code (which was in public domain, an example for SDI communication) has no problems taking 3 or less parameters but the probe I have has 7 sensors in it and I need all of their values (but all I get in return is 1, literally just the number 1). If I remove and leave only 3 sensors in the probe it works normally. So the problem is not in the communication but in the quantity of data. My code:

```c
    #include <SDISerial.h>
    #define DATALINE_PIN 2
    #define INVERTED 1

    SDISerial sdi_serial_connection(DATALINE_PIN, INVERTED);

    char* get_measurement(){
     char* service_request = sdi_serial_connection.sdi_query("?M!",60000UL);
     char* service_request_complete = sdi_serial_connection.wait_for_response(900);
     return sdi_serial_connection.sdi_query("?D0!",60000UL);
    }

    void setup(){
     sdi_serial_connection.begin(); // start our SDI connection 
     Serial.begin(9600); // start the connection
     Serial.println("OK INITIALIZED"); // startup string
     delay(90000); // startup delay to allow sensor to powerup, 1.5 min 
    }

    void loop(){
     char* response = get_measurement(); // get measurement data

     if (response!=NULL && response[0] != '\0')
      Serial.println(response);
     else
      Serial.println("No Response");
     delay(1500);
    }
```

Comment: Check the timeout values. 60000 should be 60000UL as the parameter is defined as uint32_t. The statement "uint8_t wait_for_response_ms = 180000" is also very wrong but not used. Same goes for "int j=0". Please clean up the code.

Comment: `get_measurement();` is called only once in `loop()`.

Comment: get_measurement(); within the loop is just fine, it does continuously call for the values even though it is not in classical form of a loop -again, this is a public code which i just tweeked a little to fit my needs.
However, the rest of the suggestions were spot on and thank you for that, even though it does not solve my problem it does speed up the execution.